# Multiple Numbers of dynamic Views with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

As you can see i try to build some clickable Views (with IB and Autolayout) which are completely dynamic. I get my data from my Server so until the response arrives i don´t know which View i have to show and which of theese views should be hidden.

The Problem is, that the Views i don´t need during runtime should not only be hidden but also completley removed from the `tableHeaderView`, so that the View under the removed one, comes up. I know that removing `Constraints` during runtime ist not the best choice, so i tried to set a fixed height for the four views (as NSLayoutConstraint) and if i don´t need one of theese Views i set the `Height Constraint` to zero like:

```
self.hotlineViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
```

This works fine, but now all of the Subviews making trouble (UIImageView and the Labels). Because the UIImageView also have a fixed Height and some of the Labels too. And last but not least the vertical Constraints between the Labels and its superview are also a Problem because they don´t shrink to zero automatically. I also tried to play with the priority of the Subview Constraints and it still "works" but the Warnings still remain. Any Ideas how to get this work without making a ton of NSLayoutConstraint and setting everthing to zero??

Four Views like in the Screenshot above are the maximum Number of Views, so its equal or less Views than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered putting all this inside another UITableview.

Comment: Normally a good idea, but theese Views are part of a tableHeaderView, so i don´t think this will work!

Comment: Why this needs to be your headerView, you can put these cells to the 1st section.

Comment: Its because of the Design, but it seems the only option at the Moment so i will give it a try! Thanks!